# SmartMonTools: How can I know if there is any smartctl test running on my hard disk?

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl, smart

I am **testing a hard disk** with [SmartMonTools](https://www.smartmontools.org/).

Hard disk status *prior to the testings* (only one short test performed days ago):

```
$ sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [i686-linux-3.16.0-30-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5167         -
```

So I start the **long test**:

```
$ sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [i686-linux-3.16.0-30-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in off-line mode".
Drive command "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in off-line mode" successful.
Testing has begun.
Please wait 130 minutes for test to complete.
Test will complete after Sat May  9 16:05:27 2015

Use smartctl -X to abort test.
```

The test is **supposed to be running**, then, but if I try to see its progress:

```
$ sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [i686-linux-3.16.0-30-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5167         -
```

... all I get is the same results, like if there were no running/performing tests right now.
The '-H'  parameter gives no more info:

```
$ sudo smartctl -H /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [i686-linux-3.16.0-30-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

And, as long as *there is no process running* (this test is performed by the hard disk controller alone), some `ps -e` style search should neither help.

How can I **know if there is some SMART self test running** right now?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In `smartctl -a <device>` look for `Self-test execution status`.

Example when no test is running:

```
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
```

Example while a test is running:

```
Self-test execution status:      ( 249) Self-test routine in progress...
                                        90% of test remaining.
```

When running selective self-test (`-t select`) there will also be a progress shown here:

```
SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA    MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0  125045423  Self_test_in_progress [90% left] (2881512-2947047)
```

Comment: A good idea. I suggest you to add this direct line (by grepping) as a possibility: `smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep "progress" -i -A 1` , to cut excessive info printout.

Comment: You need the excessive printout to get the whole picture though. In a script the grep may be fine, but people who are used to `grep` everything on the command line (`dmesg | grep something`, `smartctl -a | grep ...`, etc.), they will miss things. With `smartctl` in particular there is no simple command that tells you everything is okay... `smartctl -H` is a false friend in that regard.

Comment: @frostschutz "smartctl -H is a false friend in that regard." You can say that again! I too have fallen for this option once, thinking it might have to do with the self-tests...but no, entirely different subject (and purpose).

Comment: What do I do for "Device does not support Self Test logging"?

Comment: I have `Self-test execution status:` at `241` and it is telling me `10% of test remaining` for 4 hours now on a 14TB USB drive.

Comment: @Ben yes, some drives don't seem to report these correctly. Instead of `-t long` you can try selective `-t select,0-max`. Technically this does the very same thing as `-t long` but it might have a more accurate progress report in the Selective self-test log section. Personally [I use selective self-test with smaller slices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92663/30851) so I can run short daily tests. A long test run just takes ages on xx TB HDDs and not every machine runs 24/7 to let it finish.

Comment: The command ``sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX | grep "of test"`` will provide a single line with percent remaining.

Answer (score 22):

Try :

```
smartctl -c /dev/sda
```

if /dev/sda is the drive you want to check.

Comment: Edit: Sorry. I was wrong.  -c means --capabilities but it too shows the current test progress. like `60% of test remaining.`