# How to get maximum LBA of HDD (to use it with partial SMART tests)?

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl

I want to use partial SMART tests and need to give an LBA size for each span.

How can I determine the maximum LBA of my disk? (I would then divide this by 5.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `smartctl` [selective self-tests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92663/30851), you can use the `max` keyword to determine the maximum LBA for use within selective tests:

```
# smartctl -t select,0-max /dev/sda
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.9.11-arch2-1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART Selective self-test routine immediately in off-line mode".
SPAN         STARTING_LBA           ENDING_LBA
   0                    0            537234767
Drive command "Execute SMART Selective self-test routine immediately in off-line mode" successful.
Testing has begun.
```

So in this case it is 537234767 (inclusive so 537234768 total).

This is identical to the number of sectors printed by `parted` et al. but just to avoid any doubt, it's good to use `smartctl` to grab the value so there can be no possibility of disagreement regarding logical/physical sector sizes.

It also happens to start a self-test, which you can abort with `smartctl -X`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on Linux (since you used `tune2fs`), the disk and partition sizes as visible to the OS can be seen in `/proc/partitions`. E.g.

```
# head -3 /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  976762584 sda
```

The `#blocks` field is the number of 1024-byte blocks, so the number of 512-byte blocks is double that.

```
# awk '$4 == "sda" { print $3 * 2; } ' < /proc/partitions
1953525168
```

`fdisk` and `hdparm -i` can also show the number of sectors:

```
# fdisk -lu /dev/sda | head -1
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
# hdparm -i /dev/sda |grep LBAsects
 CurCHS=16383/16/63, CurSects=16514064, LBA=yes, LBAsects=1953525168
```

Yet another way would be to seek to the end of the block device, and query the offset, with e.g. Perl:

```
# perl -le '$a = sysseek(STDIN, 0, 2); print $a / 512' < /dev/sda
1953525168
```

Or, since we're about to do SMART tests anyway, ask `smartctl`:

```
# smartctl -i /dev/sda |grep  '^User Capacity:'
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
# smartctl -i /dev/sda |awk '/^User Capacity: / { gsub(",", "", $3); print $3 / 512; }'
1953525168
```

Comment: A comprehensive answer, but I am confused. My capacity is 14 TB. I have one partition. `tune2fs` gave `3.418.087.163` blocks. Your `fdisk` gave me `27.344.699.392` sectors. Why the difference in my case (you have LBA = sectors)? Also, I get `HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Invalid argument` when using `hdparm`. Maybe because it is connected via USB? And `smartctl` with `awk` gives `0.0273438`. I thought this might be because I get a European notation of capacity with `.` instead of `,`. But substituting those in the command did not work, it gave `0` as result.

Comment: `awk '$4 == "sda" { print $3 * 2; } ' < /proc/partitions` also prints `2.73447e+10` which seem to be the sector count, not LBA.

Comment: `cat /proc/partitions` is interesting. It delivers `blocks` per disk. But I have `13.672.348.655` which is about half of the sector count and about four times the LBA. Since my LBA size seems to be `4096` there might be a relation.

Comment: @Ben, ah, c**p, the numbers get too big for awk's default output format. Yeah, `/proc/partitions` gives blocks of 1024 bytes, Yes, I converted them all to 512-byte sectors. I don't think I have a disk at hand with 4096-byte sectors, so I don't know what e.g. fdisk shows for one but that's just a factor of 8 away to convert. I think `tune2fs` also gives the number of filesystem blocks, and they can be of different sizes too... Usually it'd be 4096 bytes per block for large partitions (see the `Block size:` row in the output). So yeah, `27.344.699.392` is pretty much 8 times `3.418.087.163`.

Comment: I am currently testing with the block count from `tune2fs` (3.418.087.163). I parted it into five and did five successful tests. Now, the sixth one is running, with end LBA at 4.101.704.587. So, this `block count` seems not to be the same as the LBA used by `smartctl`. Maybe I have to go with 4 or 8 times this amount.

Comment: @Ben, yeah, that's the other thing I was thinking about the block sizes and SMART, do the tests take the block offsets in 4096-byte blocks (which would be the natural for the disks), or in 512-byte blocks (which would be backward compatible). If the latter, you'd naturally get bigger numbers

Comment: I am currently trying the next set with the larger numbers and will post this information when finished.

Comment: According to frostschutz's answer your sector amount of 27 billion is the correct value, which is 8 times my reading from `tune2fs`, probably because this is the value for sectors of 512-byte blocks, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdX1` prints a lot of information, including the `block count`:

```
benraid@OMV:/srv$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdk1
tune2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Filesystem volume name:   Elements
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          e58521dc-7ac6-4096-8339-42830ceee05d
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              427261952
Block count:              3418087163
Reserved block count:     0
Free blocks:              3390863340
Free inodes:              427261941
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      418
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         4096
Inode blocks per group:   256
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Wed Dec  2 20:57:48 2020
Last mount time:          n/a
Last write time:          Wed Dec  2 21:09:13 2020
Mount count:              0
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Wed Dec  2 20:57:48 2020
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          103 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      9bccaff2-62b7-45c9-876b-b011f5e8c6b9
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0x526fb02e
```

Also interesting is `/proc/partitions` which seems to print LBA count times 4. Maybe there is a relation to the block size (4096):

```
benraid@OMV:/srv$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0 2930266584 sda
   8        1 2930265543 sda1
   8       48 2930266584 sdd
   8       49 2930265543 sdd1
   8       80 2930266584 sdf
   8       81 2930265543 sdf1
   8       32 2930266584 sdc
   8       33 2930265543 sdc1
   8       64   39082680 sde
   8       65   35221504 sde1
   8       66          1 sde2
   8       69    3858432 sde5
   8       16 2930266584 sdb
   8       17 2930265543 sdb1
   8       96 2930266584 sdg
   8       97 2930265543 sdg1
   8      112 11718885376 sdh
   8      113 11718884335 sdh1
   8      128 9766436864 sdi
   8      129 9766435823 sdi1
   8      144 11718885376 sdj
   8      145 11718884335 sdj1
   8      160 13672349696 sdk
   8      161 13672348655 sdk1
```

As ilkkachu noted in his comment, the LBA count of a partition is not spanning the correct space of the whole hard disk. But if you need just an indication of the size to use it with `smartctl -t select,0-$size` this is perfectly fine. `smartctl` will start at 0 and end at the end of the disk anyway.

Comment: Except that, 1) `/dev/sdx1` is only _a single partition_ of the disk, usually the first. There may be other partitions after it, and even if not, it doesn't necessarily span the whole disk. In any case, the partition won't start at the very beginning of the drive, there must be some space for the partition table, and usually more. 2) `tune2fs` gives information about the _file system_, which, regardless of the partition size, does not need to span even the whole partition!

Comment: With `/dev/sdx1` I wanted to express that `tune2fs` needs a partition as argument. `/dev/sdx` will not work.